# Use XSLT 2.0 to display an image from a directory

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Team,

I'm using XLST 2.0 to create MS Word documents from XML data.  I'm working on creating a header and want to call in image file from a local directory to display our company logo.  With the software I'm using, I am unable to use an MS Word Template to call.  This is billing software and needs to create each MS word document on the fly each time a bill (using XML data) get's thrown at it.

I've searched this site extensively and tried a majority of the examples given to no avail.  Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the result of the header in the MS Word doc I want to create...

[image]

Here is my XSL for the header...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" 
    xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
    xmlns:kmf="http://www.kleinmundo.com/functions" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" 
    xmlns:tlr="http://www.elite.com/functions" 
    xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" 
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" 
    xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2" 
    xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template name="XS_Header" xml:space="default">
        <xsl:variable name="TW" select="1440" />
        <xsl:variable name="image-dir" select="'/Images'" />
        <w:sectPr>
            <w:hdr w:type="first">
                <w:tbl>
                    <xsl:variable name="Col1" select="2 * $TW" />
                    <xsl:variable name="Col2" select="5.5 * $TW" />
                    <w:tblPr>
                        <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="dxa"/>
                        <w:tblCellMar>
                            <w:left w:w="0" w:type="dxa"/>
                            <w:right w:w="0" w:type="dxa"/>
                        </w:tblCellMar>
                    </w:tblPr>
                    <w:tblGrid>
                        <w:gridCol w:w="{$Col1}"/>
                        <w:gridCol w:w="{$Col2}"/>
                    </w:tblGrid>
                    <w:tr>
                        <w:trPr>
                            <w:cantSplit/>
                            <w:tblHeader/>
                        </w:trPr>
                        <!--LOGO COLUMN -->
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="{$Col1}" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:vAlign w:val="bottom"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p>
                                <w:pPr>
                                    <w:keepNext/>
                                    <w:keepLines/>
                                </w:pPr>
                                <w:r>
                                    <w:t>LOGO HERE</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                            </w:p>
                        </w:tc>
                        <!-- ADDRESS INFO COLUMN -->
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="{$Col2}" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:vAlign w:val="bottom"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p>
                                <w:pPr>
                                    <w:keepNext/>
                                    <w:keepLines/>
                                    <w:jc w:val="right" />
                                </w:pPr>
                                <w:r>
                                    <w:rPr>
                                        <w:sz w:val="16" />
                                    </w:rPr>
                                    <w:t>Company Address  |  City, State  ZIP  |  TEL 555.555.1234  |  FAX 555.555.4321</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                            </w:p>
                        </w:tc>
                    </w:tr>
                </w:tbl>
                <w:sectPr>
                    <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" w:orient="portrait" w:code="1" />
                    <w:pgMar w:top="720" w:right="720" w:bottom="720" w:left="720" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0" />
                    <w:cols w:space="720" />
                    <w:titlePg />
                    <w:docGrid w:line-pitch="272" />
                </w:sectPr>
            </w:hdr>
            <w:titlePg />
            <w:hdr w:type="odd">
            </w:hdr>
            <w:ftr w:type="first">
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t />
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:ftr>
            <w:titlePg />
            <w:ftr w:type="odd">
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t />
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:ftr>
            <w:pgNumType w:start="1" />
            <w:cols w:space="720" />
        </w:sectPr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

-Nick

Comment: XSLT does not display any images, it takes an input document and creates some result document. That can of course be a format like a HTML a browser can render and which can include images. Which MS Word format are you trying to create with XSLT? Can you show us a sample of the input, the XSLT you have and the result you want to create?

Comment: XSLT has been added to the original post.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out on my own.  Here's what I did.

I created a DOCX file with just the image in the body of document.  I then created a bookmark with the image highlighted and named the bookmark "*logo*".  I saved the DOCX file to C:\images\logo_template.docx

I then went into my XSLT file and called the DOCX file pointing to the bookmark as follows:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>
      ~INS~<xsl:value-of select"'C:\images\logo_template.docx|logo'" />~/INS~
    </w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:t>
```

This tossed the image file into the generated MS Word file I'm compiling from my bill generating software.

Best Regards,

-Nick